# What does if random.randint(0,1) mean?

Tags: python

I was reading "Foundation of python network programming, 2nd edition". And I found in page 22 a sentence which confused me. It's simplified version is  like below:

```
import random
# blah blah blah #
if random.randint(0,1):
    print "blah blah blah"
```

what does `random.randint(0,1)` do here? Does 0 equal False and 1 equal True here?

Comment: implements **pseudo-random number generators for various distributions.** you should check http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: FYI, you should be able to use Google and read the relevant documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint

Comment: The first result of google search: http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being unable to read reference docs.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: It is more about the boolean value of 0 vs. 1 than randomness.

Comment: @devnull: This isn't about the random function, it's about understanding that 0 is false in a boolean context.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's more about laziness and lack of minimal understanding about booleans.

Comment: @devnull: *That* may be the case here. I made an assumption too, that you only meant to point the OP to the randint documentation and like ThiefMaster appeared to miss the question about boolean contexts.

Comment: @devnull, I think I lack of knowledge of booleans, but not lazy. Python is the first programming language I learn. I know how to use random.randint(a,b), random.randrange(a,b), and random.choice() function. Just first time met this kind of boolean judgement. By the way, I was confused when first time I saw "While True:" statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`random.randint()` produces a random integer in the range specified, boundaries included.

Because it produces `0` or `1` at random, and numeric `0` is `False` and every other number is `True`, yes, it randomly produces a false or true value.

In Python, empty containers, empty strings, `None` and numeric 0 (integer `0`, float `0.0`, etc.) are all false values.

Comment: It's an odd way of doing it... Its intent would have been much clearer if written as: `if random.choice([False, True])`